# Apache Kafka - can't bind to an external IP address

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, apache-kafka

I've setup a basic Kafka / zookepper installation inside an Ubuntu 14.04 VM.

Testing producer / consumer locally works fine. I try to access my kafka broker from  from another host in my LAN but it doesn't work despite I configured the server.properties with

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.220:9092

    # The port the socket server listens on
    #port=9092

    # Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces
    host.name=192.168.1.220
```

and producer.properties with

```
metadata.broker.list=192.168.1.220:9092
```

but this doesn't work .. any idea ?

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: @DanielA.White no it doesn't, it's Kafka configuration related question. @EmmanuelBrunet please try setting `advertised.host.name` also

Comment: It seems you are using VirtualBox. Is your network setting NATed or bridged. Because if NATed your kafka/zk may not be reached from the outside.

Comment: Have you tried setting host.name=0.0.0.0 and exposing port 9092 on the VM in NAT settings?

Comment: see if it helps https://boristyukin.com/connecting-to-kafka-on-virtualbox-from-windows/